# Windows 'like' Start Menu

Tags: windows, menu, gnome-panel

Is there any Start Menu (that I can use along with Gnome 3) that looks like traditional Windows Start Menu? If so, It's also possible to see all open applications on the "Taskbar"?

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using? Unity or Gnome 3? Regarding the Launcher/"Taskbar" in Unity, all open applications are already visible there. They got a white arrow to the left of their icons.

Comment: Gnome 3. Sorry, I'll add it to the post. Thanks for reminding!

Comment: By Gnome 3 do you mean Gnome Shell or gnome-classic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Gnome3 I believe the closest thing to what you want would be the [applications menu extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6/applications-menu/). You can install it directly from the website.

If you like traditional DE interfaces, I think you'll like cinnamon. Its menu is the closest thing to a Windows like start menu. [Here's how it looks](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/).

To install press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. Inside the terminal run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

at login select Cinnamon instead of Unity.